# Отправка запросов на HTTP API через Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kotlin, http, ktor

У меня имеется **Http Api** на котлине, которое работает с **json**. Также имеется **html** файл с **vue**, с которого я хочу отправлять запрос по определенному адресу.

У меня есть url ***localhost:8080/v1/product***. ***Отправляя*** на него ***get запрос*** через postman, я ***получаю json*** со всеми продуктами, которые есть в ***базе данных***. Аналогично, я хочу ***отправить get запрос через vue*** на этот же адрес, чтобы в ответ ***получить json*** и вывести его на страницу. Пробовал отправлять запрос по примеру официальной документации (***через axios***), но на сервер даже не посылается get запрос. Также, я пробовал ***fetch***, но теперь до сервера просто доходил get запрос, но json также не появлялся.

**Возникает вопрос - как мне отправлять запросы на мое api, используя json и vue?**

**Github repo - https://github.com/Tushev-Dmitriy/ktor-electronic-shop**